Is there a way to exclude folders in a git repo on a specific clone
I'm looking for a way to keep track and share code between various website projects. some code is identical, some is not. Is there a way to exclude folders in a git repo on a specific clone?
Ideally i would like a layout like this:
repo:

folder A
folder B
folder C
folder D

site 1:

folder A
folder B

site 2:

folder B
folder C

site 3:

folder C
folder D

If I do this using .gitignore, the folders are not pushed to the repo, but will still be pulled. (So folder A will download to site 2 and 3).

use 'git sparse checkout' and 'gitignore' in combination

@vmicrobio THIS COMMAND IS EXPERIMENTAL. ITS BEHAVIOR, AND THE BEHAVIOR OF OTHER COMMANDS IN THE PRESENCE OF SPARSE-CHECKOUTS, WILL LIKELY CHANGE IN THE FUTURE.

yes be cautious using it as described in: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout

Wouldn't git submodules be a better solution for this?

or subtree. https://adam-p.ca/blog/2022/02/git-submodule-subtree/

Another way you can do this is by using git sparse-checkout.
For example:
git clone --no-checkout --filter=blob:none <your_repo_url>
cd <your_repository_name>
git sparse-checkout set --no-cone '/*' '.folder_you_want_to_exclude/*'
git checkout <new_branch>
I hope this helps.

Can the folders be their own repositories? If so, I would split them as such, and then use submodules to add the folders (submodules) I want for each project.
